# windowbuilder in eclipse, unsure how to display window

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

I'm fairly new to Swing, so I've been using windowbuilder to try and put together a basic GUI. The design screen works fine, but when I return to the code, it's written it in a way I'm unfamiliar with and I'm struggling to actually get it to run.

The code it generates is:

```
public class GUIControls extends JFrame{

public GUIControls() {
    getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel, "name_36737116256884");
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JButton InsertionSortButton = new JButton("Insertion Sort");
    InsertionSortButton.setBounds(32, 16, 101, 56);
    panel.add(InsertionSortButton);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel_1, "name_36737137352442");
    InsertionSortButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) getContentPane().getLayout();
            cardLayout.show(getContentPane(), "name_36737137352442");
        }
    });
}
```

(With the action taken when the button is mouseclicked being written by me, I haven't tested it because I can't run the thing)

Normally I'd do:

```
public void runGUI(){
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createGUI();

        }
    });
}
```

With createGUI being the method I used to create a (completely horrible) GUI without windowbuilder, but I can't use GUIControls in this because it doesn't work with runnable (in fact, I'm not even sure what it is when something doesn't a return value, is it still a method?).

Does anyone know how I go about running it?

Thanks

Comment: What does `GUIControls` extend from?

Comment: Ah, my bad, it's in the class GUIControls which is: public class GUIControls extends JFrame, I'll add that to the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate an instance of `GUIControls` and make it visible, for example...

```
public void runGUI(){
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            GUIControls guiControls = new GUIControls();
            guiControls.pack();
            guiControls.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            guiControls.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

ps- I know Window Builder likes to make use of `null` layouts, but I would avoid them wherever possible - IMHO

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot. Quick follow up question though, what exactly is "public GUIControls"? It's instantiated so does that mean it's a class? If so, how does it get away with not declaring itself as such? (Also I can't accept your answer for another 4 minutes, so uh...look forward to that!)

Comment: `public GUIControls` is a special method known as a constructor.  It's used to initialise a new instance of an Object.  So when you call `new GUIControls()`, Java will allocate the memory for the `Object`, initialise any instance fields and call the constructor (as specified by the `new` command)